# How to manually map Enum fields in JAX-RS

Tags: java, json, mapping, jax-rs

How can I map a simple JSON object `{"status" : "successful"}` automaticly map to my Java Enum within JAX-RS?

```
public enum Status {
    SUCESSFUL ("successful"), 
    ERROR ("error");

    private String status;

    private Status(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

If you need further details feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following `JAXB` annotations should do it. (I tested using `Jettison` but I've not tried other providers):

```
@XmlType(name = "status")
@XmlEnum
public enum Status {
    @XmlEnumValue(value = "successful")
    SUCESSFUL, 
    @XmlEnumValue(value = "error")
    ERROR;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm using standard JAX-RS features and the application server decides which implementation will be uses. In my case it's JBoss 7.1 and it uses jackson automatically (i guess). Do you know if there is a way to force jBoss using another provider? Or enable jBoss to use `XmlEnum` and `XmlEnumValue`?

Comment: It is possible that `Jackson` will behave similar to Jettison with respect to the JAXB annotations – I simply didn't have the time to try it.  BTW, if it wasn't clear, the annotations above are standard JAXB which JAX-RS implementations should follow.

Answer (score 7):

This might help you

```
@Entity
public class Process {

  private State state;

  public enum State {
    RUNNING("running"), STOPPED("stopped"), PAUSED("paused");

    private String value;

    private State(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getValue() {
      return this.value;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static State create(String val) {
      State[] states = State.values();
      for (State state : states) {
        if (state.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(val)) {
          return state;
        }
      }
      return STOPPED;
    }
  }
}
```